# mysql group and sort without using order by on outter most

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to return a list of users and their last login date. I need to get something that doesn't effect my outter order by statement because its dynamically populated by parameters the users chooses to sort the list. The other thing is the table that stores the login times requires 2 fields to link to the user table a user_id and a user_type.

```
table_admin
field: id, name

table_logs
field: id, user_id, user_type, login_date
```

*table_admin.id = table_logs.user_id

table_logs.user_type needs to be "admin"*

I need to pull all the admin users from table_admin with their last login date (it also needs to work if there is no record in the log table), the user_type in the log table would be "admin".

Thank you for your time.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS admins.*,ld2.ip,ld2.login_date as last_login 
FROM admins 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM log_logins WHERE user_type = "admin" ORDER BY login_date DESC 
) as ld2 ON (ld2.user_id = admins.id) 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY admins.id DESC LIMIT 0,40
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't grab results if they do not have an entry in the log table.

Comment: Please provide the example of your existing query.

Comment: "it doesn't grab results if they do not have an entry in the log table" - yes it does!?! Is the WHERE bit actually a variable?

Comment: Your right it does, during a test it was not but I think it was a different issue because I tried testing again later and it was working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a join with an aggregation:

```
select a.name, 'admin' as userType, max(l.login_date) as lastLoginDate
from admin a left outer join
     logs l
     on a.id = l.id and
        l.user_type = 'admin'
group by a.name
```